# Windows 8 account and MSN

Tags: windows-live-messenger, windows-8

I've installed windows 8 and during setup it wanted my email. I provided an alternative email (let's call it email_1) for the installation to complete.

Then I've installed windows live (msn only), for which I use another email (email_2).

Now, every time I start windows and open msn, I'm signed in with email_1. I selected "forget me" for email_1 address in the msn login window, but I'm somehow always signed in with email_1. Is there any way to completely remove email_1 from the msn?

Answer (score 0):

Go to your control panel: `Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Credential Manager` and simply remove the credentials you do not want associated with your device :)